# Why CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX procedure doesn't work?

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-11g-r2, data-synchronization

I'm following the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/quicktour.htm#CCAPP9015) to create indexes with Oracle Text. The problem is, when I update my data and want to synchronize my index with the `CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX` procedure (according to the step 4 of the documentation), there is no change.

I don't post my code because it is exactly the same as the documentation.

An idea about the source of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this operation, the user who executes the `SYNC_INDEX` procedure has to be the owner of the index. So, in my case, I had to give the execution rights on the package with the CTXSYS user:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON CTXSYS.CTX_DDL TO myuser;
```

Now, I can synchronize my index with *myuser*:

```
EXEC CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX('idx_docs', '2M');
SELECT SCORE(1), id, text FROM docs WHERE CONTAINS(text, 'city', 1) > 0;
```

I got the same result as the documentation:

```
  SCORE(1)         ID TEXT
---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------
         4          2 <HTML>Paris is a city in France.</HTML>
         4          4 <HTML>Los Angeles is a city in California.</HTML>
         4          5 <HTML>Mexico City is big.</HTML>
```